# Custom post type archive in sidebar widget of post

Tags: wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

This works fine. I see custom post type archive in dropdown but when I select any month, I see all custom posts on that archive page. While there is only one post in every month, for e.g. I have 1 post in month of July and 1 in August, the dropdown counter shows correct but when I select them I see all custom posts instead of just one. Is there any solution for this?

```
   add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_getarchives_where' );
    function custom_getarchives_where( $where ){
        $where = str_replace( "post_type = 'post'", "post_type IN ( 'post', 'fruits' )", $where );
        return $where;
    }

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_podcasts_to_archive' );
    function add_podcasts_to_archive( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() && !is_admin() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'fruits' ) );
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that your problem is the code in your archive page itself, are you running a custom query on your archive page

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question works. I truely suspect that your problem lies in your archive.php template.

Here are my thoughts

- you have replaced the main query with a custom query. An improper custom query on any archive page is disasterous. This is the only reason I can think of given the reason that you get **all** post from your custom post tytpe

My solution would be, delete your custom query, replace it with the default loop, and if you need any more customization, add it with `pre_get_posts`.

**EDIT**

For extra reading that might you lots in future

- [When to use a custom query and when not](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)